# Is select() + non-blocking write() possible on a blocking pipe or socket?

Tags: sockets, unix, pipe, posix, blocking

The situation is that I have a *blocking* pipe or socket fd to which I want to `write()` without blocking, so I do a `select()` first, but that still doesn't guarantee that `write()` will not block.

Here is the data I have gathered. Even if `select()` indicates that
writing is possible, writing more than `PIPE_BUF` bytes can block.
However, writing at most `PIPE_BUF` bytes doesn't seem to block in
practice, but it is not mandated by the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html).

That only specifies atomic behavior. [Python(!) documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) states that:

> Files reported as ready for writing by `select()`, `poll()` or similar
>   interfaces in this module are guaranteed to not block on a write of up
>   to `PIPE_BUF` bytes. This value is guaranteed by POSIX to be at least
>   `512`.

In the following test program, set `BUF_BYTES` to say `100000` to block in
`write()` on Linux, FreeBSD or Solaris following a successful select. I
assume that named pipes have similar behavior to anonymous pipes.

Unfortunately the same can happen with blocking sockets. Call
`test_socket()` in `main()` and use a largish `BUF_BYTES` (`100000` is good
here too). It's unclear whether there is a safe buffer size like
`PIPE_BUF` for sockets.

```c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_BYTES PIPE_BUF
char buf[BUF_BYTES];

int
probe_with_select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
                  fd_set *exceptfds)
{
    struct timeval timeout = {0, 0};
    int n_found = select(nfds, readfds, writefds, exceptfds, &timeout);
    if (n_found == -1) {
        perror("select");
    }
    return n_found;
}

void
check_if_readable(int fd)
{
    fd_set fdset;
    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(fd, &fdset);
    printf("select() for read on fd %d returned %d\n",
           fd, probe_with_select(fd + 1, &fdset, 0, 0));
}

void
check_if_writable(int fd)
{
    fd_set fdset;
    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(fd, &fdset);
    int n_found = probe_with_select(fd + 1, 0, &fdset, 0);
    printf("select() for write on fd %d returned %d\n", fd, n_found);
    /* if (n_found == 0) { */
    /*     printf("sleeping\n"); */
    /*     sleep(2); */
    /*     int n_found = probe_with_select(fd + 1, 0, &fdset, 0); */
    /*     printf("retried select() for write on fd %d returned %d\n",  */
    /*            fd, n_found); */
    /* } */
}

void
test_pipe(void)
{
    int pipe_fds[2];
    size_t written;
    int i;
    if (pipe(pipe_fds)) {
        perror("pipe failed");
        _exit(1);
    }
    printf("read side pipe fd: %d\n", pipe_fds[0]);
    printf("write side pipe fd: %d\n", pipe_fds[1]);
    for (i = 0; ; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        check_if_readable(pipe_fds[0]);
        check_if_writable(pipe_fds[1]);
        written = write(pipe_fds[1], buf, BUF_BYTES);
        if (written == -1) {
            perror("write");
            _exit(-1);
        }
        printf("written %d bytes\n", written);
    }
}

void
serve()
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    listen(listenfd, 10);

    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);

    sleep(10);
}

int
connect_to_server()
{
    int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(-1);
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        perror("inet_pton");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("connect");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return sockfd;
}

void
test_socket(void)
{
    if (fork() == 0)  {
        serve();
    } else {
        int fd;
        int i;
        int written;
        sleep(1);
        fd = connect_to_server();

        for (i = 0; ; i++) {
            printf("i = %d\n", i);
            check_if_readable(fd);
            check_if_writable(fd);
            written = write(fd, buf, BUF_BYTES);
            if (written == -1) {
                perror("write");
                _exit(-1);
            }
            printf("written %d bytes\n", written);
        }
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    test_pipe();
    /* test_socket(); */
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't want to just set the pipe/socket to non-blocking mode and be done with it?  (You can always set it back to blocking mode again after write() returns, if you feel it's necessary to do so)

Comment: This is in a language runtime, so changing blockingness would be really unfriendly to the programmer.

Comment: Not if the programmer never sees the change... if each time you set it back to the way it was, before returning control to the programmer, the programmer will never know.  (The exception would be if there are multiple threads using that same file descriptor simultaneously, but designs that do that sort of thing are doomed to grief anyway... ;))

Comment: I was hoping the avoid that. Since blocking in write() would be really bad for reasons that I omitted, the select+write logic is under a per-fd lock already, so changing blockingness back and forth seems possible. However since it is the _file description_ and not the fd that's changed by the fcntl() call, this potentially leaks to other processes.

Comment: @melisgl Wrong again. 'FD' stands for 'file descriptor', not 'file description', and its properties are local to the current process. You seem to be inventing difficulties where none exists. Unclear what you're really asking here.

Comment: @EJP, please consider reading the fcntl man page.

Comment: @melisgl I first read it in 1981. I am familiar with what it says. It does not say what you have claimed here, or anything remotely resembling it. It doesn't make any distinction between 'fd' and 'file description', and it doesn't say anything about non-blocking state 'leaking to other processes'. If you're going to cite sources at other people, make sure they support what you're claiming.

Comment: @EJP, There is an obvious disconnect somewhere. On my linux system fcntl(2) says "Duplicated file descriptors (made with dup(2), fcntl(F_DUPFD), fork(2), etc.) refer to the same open file description, and thus share the same file status flags."

Comment: There is nothing there or elsewhere about leaking to other processes. Your entire question is based on misinformation. In fact your claim that non-blocking mode applies to everyone who has the file open is preposterous. It is also completely irrelevant, as we are talking about pipes and sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you wish to send one byte at a time whenever select() says the fd is ready for writes, there is really no way to know how much you will be able to send and even then it is theoretically possible (at least in the documentation, if not in the real world) for select to say it's ready for writes and then the condition to change in the time between select() and write().

Non blocking sends are the solution here and you don't need to change your file descriptor to non blocking mode to send one message in non-blocking form if you change from using write() to send(). The only thing you need to change is to add the MSG_DONTWAIT flag to the send call and that will make the one send non-blocking without altering your socket's properties. You don't even need to use select() at all in this case either since the send() call will give you all the information you need in the return code - if you get a return code of -1 and the errno is EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK then you know you can't send any more.

Comment: Alright, that should be doable provided that it can be determined whether the fd belongs to a socket. Does staying under the PIPE_BUF limit solve the problem for pipes?

Comment: @melisgl You should note that `MSG_DONTWAIT `on `send()` is non-Posix and may not be supported on all platforms.

Comment: There is no guarantee that you will not block writing to a pipe by keeping the write size under PIPE_BUF. As you rightly stated, that only defines how many bytes are guaranteed to be delivered atomically, and it is only coincidence that the kernel pipe buffer is large enough if under this size and not behaviour that you can rely upon.

Comment: MSG_DONTWAIT is non-posix but supported at least by FreeBSD, Linux and Solaris, but not OSX. I have not investigated what other BSDs support it.

Comment: Thanks. For the record, we ended up using `MSG_DONTWAIT` for sockets, and not sending more than `PIPE_BUF` bytes for pipes (accepting the fact that the rug may be pulled from under us).

Answer (score 1):

The Posix section you cite clearly states:

> [for pipes] If the O_NONBLOCK flag is clear, a write request may cause the thread to block, but on normal completion it shall return nbyte.
>
> [for streams, which presumably includes streaming sockets] If O_NONBLOCK is clear, and the STREAM cannot accept data (the STREAM write queue is full due to internal flow control conditions), write() shall block until data can be accepted.

The Python documentation you quoted can therefore only apply to non-blocking mode only. But as you're not using Python it has no relevance anyway.

Comment: The python documentation can be right even if posix doesn't mandate the behavior it describes.

Comment: @melisgl No it can't. All it can do is call the C API. If the C API blocks. Python will block.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that Python provides anything more than a trivial wrapper around `select()`. However, a Posix compliant implementation may still provide guarantees beyond what's mandated by the spec. That's why referenced the spec, but asked for more information.

Comment: No it can't. If it calls `write()` with an amount of data that would block, it will block. And it can't tell that in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by ckolivas is the correct one but, having read this post, I thought I could add some test data for interest's sake.

I quickly wrote a slow reading tcp server (sleeping 100ms between reads) which did a read of 4KB on each cycle. Then a fast writing client which I used for testing various scenarios on write. Both were using select before read (server) or write (client).

This was on Linux Mint 18 running under a Windows 7 VM (VirtualBox) with 1GB of memory assigned.

***For the blocking case***

If a write of a "certain number of bytes" became possible, select returned and the write either completed in total immediately or blocked until it completed. On my system, this "certain number of bytes" was at least 1MB. On the OP's system, this was clearly much less (less than 100,000).

So select did *not* return until a write of at least 1MB was possible. There was never a case (that I saw) where select would return if a smaller write would subsequently block. Thus select + write(x) where x was 4K or 8K or 128K never write blocked on this system.

This is all very well of course but this was an unloaded VM with 1GB of memory. Other systems would be expected to be different. However, I would *expect* that writes below a certain magic number (PIPE_BUF perhaps), issued subsequent to a select, would never block on all POSIX compliant systems. However (again) I don't see any documentation to that effect so one can't rely on that behaviour (even though the Python documentation clearly does). As the OP says, it's unclear whether there is a safe buffer size like PIPE_BUF for sockets. Which is a pity.

Which is what ckolivas' post says even though I'd argue that no rational system would return from a select when only a single byte was available!

*Extra information:*

At no point (in normal operation) did write return anything other than the full amount requested (or an error).

If the server was killed (ctrl-c), the client side write would immediately return a value (usually less than was requested - no normal operation!) with no other indication of error. The next select call would return immediately and the subsequent write would return -1 with errno saying "Connection reset by peer". Which is what one would expect - write as much as you can this time, fail the next time.

This (and EINTR) appears to be the only time write returns a number > 0 but less than requested.

If the server side was reading and the client was killed, the server continued to read all available data until it ran out. Then it read a zero and closed the socket.

***For the non-blocking case:***

The behaviour below some magic value is the same as above. select returns, write doesn't block (of course) and the write completes in its totality.

My issue was what happens otherwise. The send(2) man page says that in non-blocking mode, send fails with EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK. Which might imply (depending on how you read it) that it's all or nothing. Except that it also says select may be used to determine when it is possible to send more data. So it can't be all or nothing.

Write (which is the same as send with no flags), says it can return less than requested. This nitpicking seems pedantic but the man pages are the gospel so I read them as such.

In testing, a non-blocking write with a value larger than some particular value returned less than requested. This value wasn't constant, it changed from write to write but it was always pretty large (> 1 to 2MB).